# How can I set the name of application diffrent at the time of "Launcher" and "share via"

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, data-sharing, android-sharing

I want to know the way to set the application name different at the time  of launcher and at the time of  browser sharing list by share .
I know sharing functionality takes place by intent filter, but I am not able to set the name different.
I want my **application name on the name of main activity** (e.g "Info Store") but name of **application in browser sharing list custom**(e.g in Share Via dialog "Add to your Info").
Currently I am getting "Info Store" at both place"

Here is my mainfest code

```
 <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.InfoStoreActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_infostore" 
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" / >
          <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
      </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of @commonsWare, I am going to post complete code of my manifest file.
  It might help to others.

```
      <activity
        android:name=.views.activities.InfoStoreActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"  

             >
         <intent-filter
             android:label="Add to Item Info"
             android:icon="@drawable/info_icon">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [`android:label` to your `<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#label) for `ACTION_SEND`, with your alternative caption.

Comment: how can we declare label in <intent-filter> ?  I think android:label is the property of activity not of intent-filter.

Comment: @kirtiHudda: Please click on the link in my answer, where I link to the documentation showing the `android:label` attribute on `<intent-filter>`.